# How to alphabetically in ascending order designers name(a-z)

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new in Magento. I need to fix the women's apparel page. on my website multiple designers products. How the designer's product display alphabetically
Ex. Ahana, Boutique, Carlisle etc.
I am working as a front-end developer/Graphic Designer.

My Website Url : https://wardrobetreasures.com/women

Comment: Hello, have you get the solution for this? if not, i will help you

Answer (score 2):

1. Be sure that you have "Used in Product Listing" and "Used for
   Sorting in Product Listing" set to "Yes" for "Name" product
   attribute
2. Then naviate to System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog >
   Frontend you will see "Product Listing Sort by" drop down menu.
   Select "Name" attribute.
3. At last refresh the cache and reindex from backend

Comment: Thanks for quick response,  its working but according to last uploading products, working as brand name not as alphabetically, who first upload with brand name that is displaying on top